# How can I use lxml to get text between empty elements

Tags: python, lxml

How can I use lxml to get text between empty elements?

Example:

```
<tagx page="1"/>Target Text<tagx page="2"/>
```

Comment: "Target text" is the `tail` of the first `<tagx>` element. See http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tail

Comment: Reviewer here: can you expand your question a little?  You're more likely to get positive feedback to your question if you explain what you've tried so far, what you searched/researched/Googled and what errors/problems you're currently encountering with the solution you're trying.

Comment: Thank you very much, @mzjn. That is what I want.

Comment: "Empty Element" is in this  [link](https://www.google.co.th/search?q=empty+elements&gws_rd=ssl)

@Kalmino I have already searched it from google and stack overflow, before I ask the question here. However my english is terrible, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

"Target Text" is the `tail` of the first `<tagx>` element.

Reference: http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tail.